# IOS Handoff link from safari to app on phone

Tags: ios, safari

I have a problem with handoff link from safari to app in my phone.

Currently, I'm developing the app that include text field that is showing the link of the site.

For example: On safari in Macbook opened "http://www.stackoverflow.com". and I want to show it on the text field in my app. I used handoff. However, I did not figure out the result.

Could you give me a solution.

Comment: Could you please show us some code what you have implemented? So that others can help,

Comment: This is code.
https://gist.github.com/cuong-nguyen-ta/e02555e8b41c7fcfab95#file-gistfile1-txt. 

I cant get url from safari to text field in my app.